# Поддержка уникальности строк в QStringLiteral

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Из справки известно, что `QStringLiteral` размещает текст непосредственно в исполняемом файле в области только для чтения. Однако я не нашёл информации о том, что в случае использования одинаковых строк в разных местах кода проекта, эти строки будут храниться по уникальности значения. Или каждый экземпляр строки будет сохранён отдельно?

Допустим, имеется сетевой запрос к некоему внешнему ресурсу. Этот запрос имеет строковую команду, скажем, "https://ru.stackoverflow.com/". Также есть два класса: `class A` и `class B`. В обоих требуется выполнять указанный запрос:

```
class A {
    void getSo() {
        sendRequest(QStringLiteral("https://ru.stackoverflow.com/"));
        // Далее выполняем что-то специфическое для класса A.
    }
};

class B {
    void getSo() {
        sendRequest(QStringLiteral("https://ru.stackoverflow.com/"));
        // Далее выполняем что-то специфическое для класса B.
    }
};
```

Вопрос заключается в том, что именно попадёт в исполняемый файл: две строки с адресом запроса или одна? Или я неверно понимаю принцип работы указанного макроса?

Comment: У Visual C++ есть ключ /GF (string pooling), но правда не написано обязан ли компилятор стого хранить их отдельно если опция не включена https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s0s0asdt.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Стандартом не оговорено.
Зависит от компилятора и настроек. Например, в Visual C++ 2015 имеется опция (зависящая от использованных параметров оптимизации)

> /GF включить объединение строк только для чтения

Так что эти литералы будут объединены. Но если скомпилировать без этого ключа или с с `/GF-`, то в exe'шнике каждая займет свое место (*при отключенной оптимизации* - включение оптимизации автоматически включает эту опцию).

Comment: Приведите источник где описан этот ключ.

Comment: `cl /?` и посмотреть на результат... Плюс он включается/отключается, судя по всему, в зависимости от настроек оптимизации.

Comment: Проверил, `GF-` нету, смотрел на vc2015

Comment: @Cerbo Вы его просто задайте в командной строке и посмотрите на результат. Но!!! **Без оптимизации**! Тот же /O2 его включит автоматически...

Comment: Вы хотите сказать - это не документированная опция?

Comment: @Cerbo, https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/s0s0asdt.aspx (на английском — https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa235442(v=vs.60).aspx).

Comment: @Cerbo Никогда не интересовался этим вопросом. Мне как-то просто все равно. Увидел вопрос. Помню, что как-то сталкивался с исходником, который вроде бы и работал на чем-то другом, а на VC++ - нет; связано было с тем, что была попытка изменения литерала, ну, типа `char* s = "Hi!"; s[1] = 'W';` - какой-то компилятор пропустил, а в VC++ - пролет. Вот тогда и познакомился с этой опцией. Насколько она работает и когда - меня не интересовало; гласное, что навсегда запомнил - строковый литерал `const` безусловный :)

Comment: @Harry Вы меня не поймете. Там нету `GF с минусом`, есть только прото `GF`

Comment: Значит, это недокументировано. Вот код `#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    char * s = "stack overflow";
    char * v = "stack overflow";
    std::cout << s << v;
}` Далее - `cl /GF- /EHsc test.cpp` вполне работает, в exe - две строки. `cl /GF /EHsc test.cpp` - тоже работает. В exe она одна. Все. Почему работает `/GF-` и почему она не описана - не знаю. Рядом с ней в `cl /?` масса опций `/G?[-]`, которые работают с минусом. Ну,  я и попробовал по аналогии...